# Accessing lowest sublist level of a list

Tags: r

I may be asking a wrong question as per there may be not another way to do what I intent, however having seen dedicated packages for lists I am going to have to ask how could I access elements on a list where its depth varies (number of sublists varies and the elements are higly embeded within sublists. I know you can access or extract elements by recursively indexing with brakets, however this becomes impractical if the numbers of sublists is large and deph of the sublists vary within the list.

I aim to acess the sublists as to catch and change all integer(0) elements within the sublists and change them to NULL or 0. I know from other reponses that you could use length as to evaluate if there are integer(0) elements in absence of empty lists, however the main issue resides on acessing the lowest level in another way than bracket indexing. (unlist will work only for exiting items not the case for integer(0)). length will work for perfect indexing via brakets and lengths one level above length as per length(x[[i]]).

```
x <- list(list(list(c(1,2)),list(c(3,4))),list(list((integer(0)),c(7,8) )))

str(x) 

List of 2
$ :List of 2
..$ :List of 1
.. ..$ : num [1:2] 1 2
..$ :List of 1
.. ..$ : num [1:2] 3 4
$ :List of 1
..$ :List of 2
.. ..$ : int(0) 
.. ..$ : num [1:2] 7 8

x[[1]][[1]][[1]] # the first element in sublist 1
# 1 2 
x[[2]][[1]][[1]] # the first element in sublist 2
# integer(0)
length (x[[2]][[1]][[1]])
[1] 0
lengths(x[[2]][[1]]) # will work by going one way down the sublist as to check for length.
```

EDIT :

if x will have further downleves than above the situation the proposed solutions from the comments or answer will not goo deep enough to measure the length of elements and extract integer(0) and it will not work. How would then would you go about it.

```
x <- list(list(list(list(list(c(1,2)),list(c(3,4))),list(list((integer(0)),c(7,8) )))))

str(x) 
List of 1
$ :List of 1
..$ :List of 2
.. ..$ :List of 2
.. .. ..$ :List of 1
.. .. .. ..$ : num [1:2] 1 2
.. .. ..$ :List of 1
.. .. .. ..$ : num [1:2] 3 4
.. ..$ :List of 1
.. .. ..$ :List of 2
.. .. .. ..$ : int(0) 
.. .. .. ..$ : num [1:2] 7 8
```

Comment: Did you think about using `unlist` with `recursive=F` and `lapply`? It's still not clear what you're asking. `Map(lengths,x)`, `lapply(x,function(y) Map(lengths,y))`...

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you have `?rapply` in mind? E.g. `str(rapply(x, function(x) if(!length(x)) 0L else x, how = "replace"))`

Comment: @Philip , Unlist will not work, and the first function philip suggest lies three levels above the sublist where the elements lie, the scond one is two levels above where elements reside in the real data (SEE EDIT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `rapply()`, the recursive version of `lapply()`, works in your case.

Try this:

```
y <- rapply(x, f = function(x)if(length(x)==0) 0 else x, how = "list")
str(y)

List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:2] 1 2
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:2] 3 4
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : num 0
  .. ..$ : num [1:2] 7 8
```

Comment: Any clues on how would you go into deeper levels as per formulation beyond the use of lengths see EDIT

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question.  My answer still works on your edited question.